# How to use MVC Bundling + Service Worker Cache

Tags: caching, model-view-controller, service-worker, bundling-and-minification

**Problem**

If I load the page without a service worker, everything is fine but when I introduce a service worker, the page does not load the first time (when online) because it is missing my bundled files which causes both CSS and Script issues. If I refresh the page then everything works because the service worker caches fetch requests when they occur.

**Setup**

Say I have a bundle such as

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/main").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/moment.min.js",
    "~/node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"));
```

and a service worker in my root directory such as

```
var cacheName = 'v1:static';

self.addEventListener('install', function (e) {
e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function (cache) {
        return cache.addAll([
            '/images/keypad/number 0.png',
            '/',
            '/Menu/MainMenu',
            '**TODO: Cache Bundles**'
        ]).then(function () {
            self.skipWaiting();
        });
    })
);
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    if (event.request.method != "POST") {
        event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                return response;
            }

            fetch(event.request).then(function (fetchResponse) {
                caches.open(cacheName).then(function (cache) {
                    cache.put(event.request, fetchResponse.clone());
                });

                return fetchResponse;
            });
        })
    );
}
});
```

**Question**

How do I cache my bundled files in my service worker, in both Debug and Release mode because debug displays them as individual files while Release will combine them, and I don't know the URLs to the bundles?

**Additional Thoughts**

You can't put a Razor @... in this file because it isn't cshtml.

I don't want to list every file out in both places and maintain both.

I thought about using a server side handler to generate my service-worker.js file but I was wondering if there is an actual clean way to do this without going crazy.

Thank You!

Comment: This is what I do `"/bundles/bundlename?v=x"` and it works

Answer (score 0):

1. @Scripts.Url("~/bundles/yourBundleName") use this to get the absolute URL for the URL from there you can get the bundle name map that into a variable and use that variable in service worker install event so that assets are cached on load itself.

note: 
*one mistake which i used to do Also please don’t refer serviceworker.js file directly in to index.html, this will be loaded at the time of registering from sw-registration.js file*